# Inconsistent behavior of View on Site Link in Web 8

Tags: web8, dxa, sdl-cloud

For published pages I am seeing inconsistent behavior of "View on Site" button in Context Menu and in Ribbon. PFA screenshots.

**Disabled:**

[image]

Within 3-4 sec in next click it is 
**Enabled:**

[image]

The CME logs and Event viewer does not throw any error at least I don't see them.

One more thing to notice here - If click 2nd time on the same page its gets enabled. could this be any service delaying it's response... `/WebUI/Comunication.svc` or something

I am not sure where to check this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if that is by design or not, but I'm seeing similar behavior in one of our Web 8.5 evnvironments. Seems the view on site link enablement is a bit slow loading. Have you contacted Customer Support about this issue and requested their response on it?

Comment: Exactly.. it indeed seems slow..or stuck due to some event/action. I would have it checked by CS.

Comment: @Vikas, I have seen the similar behavior with in-house SDL web 8 and cloud based web 8.5. I am not sure, if this is by design of this functionality but I can say this is not an issue as it take some to time to highlight the link(View on site) but link always work.

Comment: Yeah thats right. Its not an issue but its a concern on why it is behaving like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The View On Site button is only enabled if the current Publication has a Business Process Type associated with it. For the UI to know that, it needs to load the Publication. That is why there is a slight delay the first time -- but the next time you select a Page, the Publication is already loaded and there is no delay.

Comment: Aah.. this seems the exact behavioral reason.